# finding "valleys" in a number sequence

Tags: r

For this question, I am not exactly looking for a valley, but a way to identify the repeating "valleys" in the number sequence.

I have this data

```
x <- c(1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,2,2,2,3)
```

so I have tried the following:

```
test <- data.frame(x)

test <- test %>% mutate(Lag = c(tail(x, -1), NA))

which(test$x > test$Lag)+1
```

which netted me the positions of 5 and 12.

The question is, how do I get the code to identify the remaining "valleys" in the number sequence. Expected output will be to identify positions of 5, 6 and 12, 13, 14.

It is somewhat similar to the local minima in time series but that is not what I am looking for.

I would also like to identify these as blocks; like positions of 5, 6 as belonging to category 1 and 12, 13, 14 as belonging to category 2.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can also do this with `rle` from `base R`

```
v1 <- seq_along(x)*inverse.rle(within.list(rle(x),
         {i1 <- c(0, diff(values))<0; values <- i1}))
v1[v1!=0]
#[1]  5  6 12 13 14
```

Comment: It's better to change `c(0, diff(values))<0` to `c(0, diff(values))<0 & c(diff(values,differences =2),0)<0`. The former means a step down, and the latter means a valley. But both work fine with the example data.

Comment: supported your solution as it dealt with a scenario like ```x <- c(1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1,3,3,3,1,1,1,2,2,2,1,1,1)```. does not understand your code though.. what kind of logic is the code following? and how does Feng's solution come in?

Comment: @bzzbzzRzzbzz  The `rle` gives a `list` of `values and `lengths` for the adjacent values that are same. .  what we did was to take the difference of 'values' check if it is less than 0 to find the index of local minima and then assign those to 'values' so that all other values will be FALSE and only those that satsify the conditions becomes TRUE.  When we multiply with sequence of 'x', (`seq_along(x)`), (the FALSE will get coerce to 0 and others 1), leading to a vector of 0;s and sequence index.  THen, we subset the values that are not 0 (`v1[v1!=0]`)

Comment: @akrun is there a way to categorize the chunks, like 5,6 as category 1 and 12,13,14 as category 2? sorry have been trying but really could not think of a solution

Comment: @akrun further found this.. I ranked the values by a increasing sequence first, then I use this ```split(df$rank, cumsum(c(1, diff(df$rank) != 1)))```, which splitted the groups up

Comment: @bzzbzzRzzbzz  You can create a grouping variable with `rleid` i.e `library(data.table); setNames(v1[v1!=0], as.integer(factor(rleid(v1!=0)[v1!=0])))`

Answer (score 2):

This might be resolved using `cummax`. Using your `x`,

```
cummax(x)
#  [1] 1 1 2 2 2 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 3 3 3
which(x != cummax(x))
# [1]  5  6 12 13 14
x[x != cummax(x)]
# [1] 1 1 2 2 2
```

You are given 5-6 and 12-14, and then you know to which categories each is assigned. You can group them perhaps more meaningfully using `split` or some binning function.

Answer (score 1):

We could do it with regular expressions (valley means a `negative slope` followed by `0 slopes` followed by a `positive slope` in `x`, assuming that the slopes are `-1, 0` and `1` as in the input data, but we can generalize):

```
pattern <- 'N([0]+)P' # \_.._/
txt <- gsub('1', 'P', gsub('-1', 'N', paste(diff(x), collapse='')))
matched <- gregexpr(pattern,txt)
positions <- unlist(matched) + 1
lengths <- attr(matched[[1]], "match.length") - 2 # exclude N & P
valley.points <- lapply(1:length(positions), function(i)seq(positions[i], positions[i]+lengths[i],1))

#[[1]]
#[1] 5 6

#[[2]]
#[1] 12 13 14

plot(x, type='l')
points(unlist(valley.points), x[unlist(valley.points)], pch=19, col='red')
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting approach, I would not have thought to use textual regular expressions for numerical analysis. Creative!